# Copy Files using a batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I need to copy a set of files mentioned in the loop to another location with each file copied into a directory that is named after the file name.

Example :
I need to copy file1.txt from path ABC to DEF\file1\ ;
file2.txt from path ABC to DEF\file2\

I have been trying to use this following for loop to achieve the same thing. however there seems to be a syntax error with what I am doing. because of the hurry to deliver this, I could not explore much before posting it here. I am searching for solutions in parallel. Please let me know the issue with the code sample  below

```
FOR %%file IN (de.txt en.txt es.txt fr.txt it.txt ja.txt nl.txt pt.txt zh_CN.txt) DO  
     SET name=%file%.*
    echo f | xcopy /I /Y "C:\textfiles\%name%.txt" D:\textfiles\%name%\LanguageFile.txt
DONE
```

Comment: Is the actual error message you are getting a secret?

Comment: :) %file was unexpected at this time

Comment: I've never seen the DONE word in in the windows loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from the command line

```
for %f in (de.txt en.txt es.txt fr.txt it.txt ja.txt nl.txt pt.mo zh_CN.txt) do echo xcopy "C:\textfiles\%~nf.mo" "D:\textfiles\%~nf\%~nf.mo"
```

or in  batch file

```
for %%f in (de.txt en.txt es.txt fr.txt it.txt ja.txt nl.txt pt.mo zh_CN.txt) do echo xcopy "C:\textfiles\%%~nf.mo% "D:\textfiles\%%~nf\%%~nf.mo"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%f IN (de.txt en.txt es.txt fr.txt it.txt ja.txt nl.txt pt.txt zh_CN.txt) DO (
  ECHO ECHO f bar xcopy /I /Y "C:\textfiles\*%%f*" u:\textfiles\%%~nf\LanguageFile.txt
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Simply `echo`es the command to be executed. If correct, change `ECHO f bar` to `f|` to actually copy

Comment: I saw this `echo f |` sometimes before `xcopy` and have no clue what it should do.

Comment: @endoro it replies `f` for `f`ile to the xcopy question `file or directory`. There is an option to auto-reply 'directory', but in standard Micro$oft fashion, none to reply `file`. Of course, if the destination terminates `\` then the destination is assumed to be matching-name file(s) within the specified directory.